# Wait for a Promise before to get my Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, promise, observable

I want to do an Http Request with a token I took from storage.
Basically with a synchronous function to get my token the code looks like:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, XHRBackend, Response, Request, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { StorageProvider } from '../../providers/storage/storage';

@Injectable()
export class SecureHttp extends Http {

  constructor(backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions,
    private store: StorageProvider) {

    super(backend, options);
  }

  request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    let __token = this.store.getToken();

      // ... some verifications ...

    options.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${__token}`);
    return super.request(url, options)
  }
}
```

I'm happy with that.. but when I changed my synchronous storage access with an asynchronous storage..:

```
public getToken(): Promise<string> {
  return this.storage.get('token');
}
```

and

```
  request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    this.store.getToken().then((token) => {
      options.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
      return super.request(url, options)
    });
  }
```

my compiler says:

> [ts] A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must
>   return a value.

Or

```
  request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    let __token;
    this.store.getToken().then((token) => {
      __token = token;
    });
    options.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${__token}`);
    return super.request(url, options)
  }
```

__token is null when the request is performed.

How can I integrate my Promise in my Observable :)
Thanks

Comment: I don't have time to put together a full answer right now, but maybe [fromPromise](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/frompromise.html) might be of use to you.

Answer (score 0):

> `Promise<string>`

Once you depend on a promise to resolve, its going to be *Promise* based all the way up (Just like any other async process e.g. callbacks all the way up, observable all the way up) etc.

## Fix

Change:

```
request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): 
  Observable<Response> {
      let __token = this.store.getToken();
```

To add [`Promise` and `async/await`](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/async-await.html):

```
async request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): 
  Promise<Observable<Response>> {
      let __token = await this.store.getToken();
```

Comment: it's an extended class I cannot change this signature function..?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @sam-herrmann & @than in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/48664801/9115215 for the **fromPromise**

```
  request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return Observable.fromPromise(this.store.getToken()).concatMap((token) => {
      options.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
      return super.request(url, options)
    })
  }
```